# Query issue of datetime datatype to date

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to load data from access database with query using CAST to change the datatype to date in c#.But when i typed in the textbox to enter the parameter for date for the parameters it gives me ierrorinfo.getdescription failed with e_fail.

Code

```
 connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string start = textBox1.Text;
            string end = textBox2.Text;
            string query = "SELECT dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.workordercurID,dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.workordercode,CAST(dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime AS DATE) AS [Close Date],CAST(dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.RequiredbyDtime AS DATE) AS [Required By Date] " +
                "FROM dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR1 " +
                "WHERE (((CAST(dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime AS DATE))>=@start And (CAST(dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime AS DATE))<=@end));";
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@start", start));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@end", end));
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt5);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt5;
            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error. Try to debug. Also try specifying the data type for the parameter eg: command.Parameters.Add("@start", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp)

Comment: Should be at dataGridView1.DataSource = dt5; It pop the error when i run with the breakpoint.

Comment: I think  the function **Cast** is not exist in Ms-Access, use **Cdate** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to cast the values. Use *DateTime* when dealing with date and time:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        string query = "SELECT dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.workordercurID,dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.workordercode,dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime, dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.RequiredbyDtime " +
            "FROM dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR1 " +
            "WHERE dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime >= @start And dbo_RSWORKORDERCUR.closeDtime <= @end;";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@start", OleDbType.Date));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@end", OleDbType.Date));
        command.Parameters["@start"].Value = start;
        command.Parameters["@end"].Value = end;
```

Comment: Using this i am receiving the error no value given for 1 or more parameter

Comment: That is weird. Typically, that indicates a misspelled field or table name.

Comment: The query works in access but when its at visual studio c# it did not work when the parameters are keyed

Comment: I can't check it out. But its the common syntax so double-check your values.